# Javascript having a date from array only printed once

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an array with events, and show them via FlatList in react native, which works fine. But on some dates there are multiple events, meaning it also prints out the dates multiple times.

How can I only print out the date (on which there are multiple events) just once.

This is the code to render the row:

```
renderRow({item}) {
    const eventdate = moment(item.start.dateTime);
    const today = (moment() == eventdate) ? styles.today : undefined;
    const date = item.start.dateTime;
    return (
        <View style={styles.datesContainer}>
            {date ?
                <View style={styles.day}>
                    <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={[styles.dayNum, today]}>{moment(date).format('DD')}</Text>
                    <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={[styles.dayText, today]}>{moment(date).format('dd')}</Text>
                </View>
            :
                <View style={styles.day}/>
            }
            <View style={[styles.item, {height: item.height}]}>
                <Text style={styles.itemtitle}>{item.summary}</Text>
                <Text>{moment(item.start.dateTime).format('HH:mm')} - {moment(item.end.dateTime).format('HH:mm')}</Text>
                <Text>{item.description}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

So I only want to print the date once, even is there are multiple events on that date. So basically having an empty view for alignment.

This is what the data dump looks like:

```
'row', { kind: 'calendar#event',
etag: '"etag"',
id: 'ID',
status: 'confirmed',
htmlLink: 'html link',
created: '2017-12-13T10:44:49.000Z',
updated: '2017-12-13T13:09:07.860Z',
summary: 'title',
creator: { email: 'email' },
organizer: 
{ email: 'cal email',
 displayName: 'displayname',
 self: true },
start: 
{ dateTime: '2018-04-08T08:45:00+02:00',
 timeZone: 'Europe/Amsterdam' },
end: 
{ dateTime: '2018-04-08T09:30:00+02:00',
 timeZone: 'Europe/Amsterdam' },
recurringEventId: 'recurringEventId',
originalStartTime: 
{ dateTime: '2018-04-08T08:45:00+02:00',
 timeZone: 'Europe/Amsterdam' },
iCalUID: 'icalUID',
sequence: 0 }
'row', { kind: 'calendar#event',
etag: '"etag"',
id: 'ID',
status: 'confirmed',
htmlLink: 'html link',
created: '2017-12-13T10:44:49.000Z',
updated: '2017-12-13T13:09:07.860Z',
summary: 'title',
creator: { email: 'email' },
organizer: 
{ email: 'cal email',
 displayName: 'displayname',
 self: true },
start: 
{ dateTime: '2018-04-08T10:00:00+02:00',
 timeZone: 'Europe/Amsterdam' },
end: 
{ dateTime: '2018-04-08T13:00:00+02:00',
 timeZone: 'Europe/Amsterdam' },
recurringEventId: 'recurringEventId',
originalStartTime: 
{ dateTime: '2018-04-08T10:00:00+02:00',
 timeZone: 'Europe/Amsterdam' },
iCalUID: 'icalUID',
sequence: 0 }
```

As you can see there are 2 events on the same date, but with different starting times.

Comment: please show example array you are listing

Comment: It's an array coming from a google calendar.

Comment: Change the sensitive information and paste a screenshot of it on your question please ( or dump data with the same structure ). We need to know how the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

How about have a `this.globalDate` to check if you want to show the date or not, like:

```
renderRow({item}) {
    ...
    const date = item.start.dateTime;
    let isShowDate = False;
    if (this.globalDate !== date) {
        isShowDate = True;
    }
    else {
        this.globalDate = date;
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.datesContainer}>
            {date && isShowDate ?
            ....
        </View>
    )
}
```

This works if you are getting `sorted data` back from the API. Otherwise, use an array to store all dates and check if the `date` is already showing ( in the datesArray ) like:

```
renderRow({item}) {
    ...
    const date = item.start.dateTime;
    let isShowDate = True;
    if (this.globalDates.includes(date)) {
        isShowDate = False;
    }
    else {
        this.globalDates.push(date);
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.datesContainer}>
            {date && isShowDate ?
            ....
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is always true, where is the globalDate defined?

Comment: And it is sorted by start datetime btw.

Comment: you declare it inside `constructor`. `constructor(props){this.globalDate = "";}`

Comment: Still always true, so maybe the array check would be better?

Comment: Updated my answer with example for array used

Comment: Thanks, only no dates are shown not even single ones.

Comment: In split sec, it seems to show the dates, but then removes them again.

Comment: If you re-render screen somewhere else, then we need to initiate `this.globalDates = []` because the array contains all the dates and ofcourse they will not show if you have them in the array. If you don't want to do it, then use string `this.globalDate` instead, and your data is sorted so it will always works